# Why does expressing the Faddeev-Popov determinant as this lead to such problems?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, yang-mills, partition-function, ghosts, functional-determinants

**Background**

In the following, I am interested in the Schwinger function associated with the gluon propagator when one considers the Gribov no-pole condition in the partition function. Defining $\nabla^{ac}_\mu = \delta^{ac}\partial_\mu+f^{abc}A^b_\mu$, usually this is written like this:
\begin{align}
Z=&\int_\Omega \mathcal{D}A\,\det(-\partial_\mu \nabla_\mu)e^{-\int d^4x \left(\frac{1}{4g^2}(F^a_{\mu \nu})^2+\frac{1}{2\xi g^2}(\partial_\mu A^a_\mu)^2\right)}\tag{1}
\\
=&\int_\Omega \mathcal{D}A \int \mathcal{D} \bar{c} \mathcal{D} c\,e^{-\int d^4x \left(\frac{1}{4g^2}(F^a_{\mu \nu})^2+\frac{1}{2\xi g^2}(\partial_\mu A^a_\mu)^2\right)+\int d^4x\,\bar{c}^a (\partial_\mu \nabla_\mu)^{ab} c^b}. \tag{2}
\end{align}
Where $\Omega$ is the integration domain defined by the Gribov no-pole condition on the propagator of the Faddeev-Popov ghosts $c^a$. The procedure used to modify the gluon propagator according to this condition is exposed in [Gribov Ambiguity](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.11659) by Thitipat Sainapha EQs. $(3.77)-(3.85)$. However, [Heat kernel expansion: user's manual](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0306138) by D. V. Vassilevich tells us that we can express the determinant in $(1)$ according to $(4.28)$ which gives, with the notations of the subsection $2.1$:
\begin{align}
\det(-\partial_\mu \nabla_\mu )=& e^{\frac{1}{16\pi^2}\int d^4x \left( \frac{1}{12}\Omega^{ac}_{\mu \nu}\Omega^{ca}_{\mu \nu}+\frac{1}{6}\overline{\nabla}^{ab}_\mu \overline{\nabla}^{bc}_\mu E^{ca}+\frac{1}{2}E^2 \right)}
\\
=&e^{\frac{1}{16\pi^2}\int d^4x \left(\frac{1}{12}\Omega^{ac}_{\mu \nu}\Omega^{ca}_{\mu \nu}+\frac{1}{3}\partial_\mu A^{ab}_\mu \partial_\nu A^{ba}_\nu\right)}.\tag{3}
\end{align}
With $\overline{\nabla}^{ac}_\mu = \delta^{ac}\partial_\mu+\frac{1}{2}f^{abc}A^b_\mu=\delta^{ac}\partial_\mu+A^{ac}_\mu$, $E^{ab} = \partial_\mu A_\mu^{ab}$ and $\Omega^{ab}_{\mu \nu} = [\overline{\nabla}^{ac}_\mu ; \overline{\nabla}^{cb}_\nu]$. Then, inserting $(3)$ inside $(1)$ gives a partition function that doesn't depend on any ghost.

**The problem**

As you can see, since there are no ghosts, there is apparently no way to counter the self-energy $p$ dependence by a counter-term at a one-loop level. The only way I've found to get rid of this problem is by first reintroducing $g_s$ in the covariant derivatives and then rescaling as follows:
\begin{equation}
\left\{ \begin{matrix} g_s \leadsto g_s\times h \\A_\mu \leadsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{h}} A_\mu \end{matrix} \right. .\tag{4}
\end{equation}
After this manipulation, we can choose $g$ so that the cubic terms in the lagrangian cancel each other. Note that this worked because the cubic terms have the same prefactor $\propto f^{abc}$ (contrarily to the quartic terms which are not the same at all) and have opposite signs.

I have gone further on my side up to the one-loop two-point correlation function of the theory since the propagator now has a mass thanks to the Gribov no-pole condition (the self-energy is a constant), but I would like to know if this manipulation is correct...

**Questions**

Is there a fundamental reason why expressing the Faddeev-Popov determinant with ghosts seems to be the 'right way' of doing this all, as opposed to the troublesome $(3)$?

If it turns out to be OK to express the determinant with $(3)$, is the rescaling $(4)$ the only way to solve the problem of the cubic interaction terms that give a self-energy that can't be countered by the associated counter-term?